# Auto close expander

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have used an expander control to create some sort of slide-out panel which holds some filtering options. The users have the option to 'pin' this expander to the view. All went well but now I would like to know how I can get the expander to auto close when the user clicks somewhere out of the expander. I tried the LostFocus and several other events but to no avail. Which event can inform me when the user has clicked somewhere else?

(For the moment I'm just using a timer which closes the expander after +- 2 seconds after the mouse left the expander but I would prefer the other solution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your `Expander` is named "yourExpander" you could do this:

```
<Window PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown"
```

If `e.OriginalSource` is not a descendant of your expander close your expander:

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Visual visual = e.OriginalSource as Visual;

    if (!visual.IsDescendantOf(yourExpander))
        yourExpander.IsExpanded = false;
}
```

Comment: I had to use e.OriginalSource instead of e.Source, otherwise I always get the Window(actualy usercontrol in my case) as the source. I'll mark it as the answer nonetheless :)

I do however still have some problems with datetimepickers and comboboxes. When selecting values in these controls they aren't considered as descendants so my expander closes.

Answer (score 0):

To allow my users to automatically expand the Expander when the mouse is over any part of it, and close it when not, I used the following code;

In the viewModel add a MenuIsVisible property, a closeMenu method, an openMenu method, and 2 ICommands; CloseExpanderCommand and OpenExpanderCommand

```
public class TripsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private bool _menuIsVisible;
    public bool MenuIsVisible
    {
        get=>_menuIsVisible;
        set
        {
            if (value == _menuIsVisible) { return;}
            _menuIsVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void CloseExpander() { MenuIsVisible = false;}
    private void OpenExpander() { MenuIsVisible = true;}

    public ICommand CloseExpanderCommand { get; }
    public ICommand OpenExpanderCommand { get; }
```

in your view:
make sure you reference:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

then

```
<Border >
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenExpanderCommand}" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseExpanderCommand}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <Expander Tag="Menu"
              ExpandDirection="Right"
              Header="Menu"
              IsExpanded="{Binding MenuIsVisible}">
            <StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
       </Expander>
    </Border>
```

The event triggers are where the magic happens.